# MySQL Bad query slows entire server

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, slowdown

Sometimes when I submit a long query and kill the thread before its done, the entire server slows down, even after a complete reboot of the system, and nothing is showing up in the process list in mysql...even if I stop the MySQL service. I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 and Mysql 5.5, are there any OS level processes that MySQL might have started that keep working after MySQL stops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a corruption issue. Killing certain processes seem to cause problems in the table... Ended up restoring a backup and the issue was resolved. Must have been repair processes in the background.